Conditional Expectation - Geometric Brownian Motion
Given a stock dynamics following Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM) such that
$$dS_t = rS_tdt+\sigma S_tdW_t.$$
Then, the stock price at $t+\Delta t$ can be expressed as $$S_{t+\Delta t} = S_{t}\exp\left((r-\sigma^2/2)\Delta t+\sigma \sqrt{\Delta t} \epsilon\right),$$
where $\epsilon\sim N(0,1).$
I am wondering if $$\mathbb{E}\left[S_{t+\Delta t}|0 \leq S_{t+\Delta t}<s_2, S_t \geq s_1\right]=\int_0^{s_2}s_{t+\Delta t}f(s_{t+\Delta t}|S_t\geq s_1) ds_{t+\Delta t},$$
where $$f(s_{t+\Delta t}|S_t> s_1) = \frac{1}{s_{t+\Delta t}\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2\Delta t}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\ln(s_{t+\Delta t})-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2\Delta t}\right).$$
Here, $\mu=(r-\sigma^2/2)\Delta t+\ln(s_1)$, $s_1$ and $s_2$ are two pre-defined constants.
